# Flashing Issue When Switching Tabs in Dark Mode: How to Solve this Problem?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm encountering a flashing problem randomly when switching between tabs in dark mode on my Tauri web app. The flash might be caused by the browser rendering or the operating system's handling of tab switching. I suspect that the JavaScript code responsible for toggling between dark and light modes might be contributing to this issue. Secondly, the sidebar unexpectedly closes and opens again, during this weird bug.

[image]

Here's an overview of the relevant Javascript:

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const sidebar = body.querySelector('nav');
const toggle = body.querySelector('.toggle');
const modeSwitch = body.querySelector('.toggle-switch');
const modeText = body.querySelector('.mode-text');

// Check if dark mode preference is stored in localStorage
const isDarkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode') === 'true';
// Check if sidebar preference is stored in localStorage
const isSidebarClosed = localStorage.getItem('sidebarClosed') === 'true';

// Set initial state based on stored preferences
if (isDarkMode) {
  body.classList.add('dark');
  modeText.innerText = 'Light mode';
} else {
  body.classList.remove('dark');
  modeText.innerText = 'Dark mode';
}

if (isSidebarClosed) {
  sidebar.classList.add('close');
} else {
  sidebar.classList.remove('close');
}

toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidebar.classList.toggle('close');
  // Store sidebar state in localStorage
  const isClosed = sidebar.classList.contains('close');
  localStorage.setItem('sidebarClosed', isClosed);
});

modeSwitch.addEventListener('click', () => {
  body.classList.toggle('dark');
  // Store dark mode state in localStorage
  const isDark = body.classList.contains('dark');
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', isDark);

  if (isDark) {
    modeText.innerText = 'Light mode';
  } else {
    modeText.innerText = 'Dark mode';
  }
});

// Add the 'dark' class to the body element if dark mode preference is stored
if (isDarkMode) {
  body.classList.add('dark');
}
```

I would like to know if there's a way to modify the JavaScript code or make any necessary adjustments to the CSS to mitigate the flashing issue and to ensure that the sidebar remains in its current state without closing and reopening. I want to ensure a smooth transition between tabs when in dark mode.

Comment: _"or the operating system's handling of tab switching"_ - you are talking about tabs implemented in HTML, JS and CSS here, no? Then how would the OS be involved with this ...? We can't currently see how your are doing that tab switching, you'll need to provide us with a proper [mre] so that we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the Dashboard link in menu actually does a RELOAD of the page, then your issue is that upon initial (re)load of the page you are loading the Light theme by default, then JS executes and applies the Dark theme... that is why you are seeing the flash

You can fix this by loading the proper/dark theme with the initial page load, which would mean to have saved the theme=dark in a cookie or SESSION and based on its value do the initial load from the backend, instead of applying it via JS on the frontend.

Comment: I am still newbie in all of this stuff and this sounds like the right solution. Can you elaborate further on the topic? How do I make/save the proper theme=dark? And then save it to a cookie or session and based on its value do the initial load from the backend?

Comment: Depending on your backend you need to explore that. It is not clear what you use as backend... and I am sure that for each language there are plenty of tutorial on how to save a value to COOKIE or SESSION and then read it